# Stripe error: Network error [errno 77]: The one-time function was previously called and failed. Its error code is no longer available

Tags: php, stripe-payments

My site hasn't been able to accept payments for a few hours now. I've been getting this error message:

```
Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. 
If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. 
(Network error [errno 77]: The one-time function was previously 
called and failed. Its error code is no longer available)
```

I'm running PHP through Apache and the code hasn't changed. I recently updated my server's packages to pick up SSL updates. Could that be causing a problem?

Comment: Have you tried writing to support@stripe.com?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by restarting Apache.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux. Restart php-fpm and nginx it should work too.

Comment: When I executed this answer, the error was resolved successfully.